# first attempts at creating Application Project result in java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, adt

I have downloaded the ADT bundle (yesterday), unzipped it, opened Eclipse and followed the directions from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html to set it up. I then followed the directions on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html to Build First App.  Each time - and I have been trying for two days, several hours each - I get the same error after I click "finish".

*Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'Testing'.
java.lang.NullPointerException*

I have checked and double checked that all the folders are correctly placed. I have accepted all the default settings. I haven't changed anything, just followed instructions.

I'm on a Macbook Pro OSX 10.8.4. using ADT Build: v22.0.1-685705.

I'd appreciate some advice.

Comment: Did you try the same using Android Studio? If not, could you, and maybe post some more info about the stacktrace?

Comment: right click on the project and go to the option android tools->>fix project properties. and u can check also add support library in same option.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I get the same now. not sure how to proceed.. any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened to me but using Windows. In the end I opted to just download the bundle that includes all you need, no hassle: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html